# Find missing entries by date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two redshift tables:

- alert_type: where i keep types of alerts in my system
- alert: where i keep alerts

Every day I generate a new alert for each alert type. If something has failed in application side I will be missing an entry in `alert` table. So I'm trying to write a query to get `alert_type`'s that are missing and date for which they are missing.

```
(SELECT
        CAST (p0.n + p1.n*2 + p2.n * POWER(2,2) + p3.n * POWER(2,3)+ p4.n * POWER(2,4)+ p5.n * POWER(2,5) AS INT) AS days
          FROM
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p0,
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p1,
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p2,
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p3,
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p4,
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p5
    WHERE (p0.n + p1.n*2 + p2.n * POWER(2,2) + p3.n * POWER(2,3)+ p4.n * POWER(2,4)+ p5.n * POWER(2,5)) <= 31
    )
```

Since there is an issue with `generate_series` running only on leader node I'm using this query to generate last 30 dates.

```
SELECT DATE(CURRENT_DATE - CAST ( days AS INT )) AS dt
    FROM
     (SELECT
        CAST (p0.n + p1.n*2 + p2.n * POWER(2,2) + p3.n * POWER(2,3)+ p4.n * POWER(2,4)+ p5.n * POWER(2,5) AS INT) AS days
          FROM
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p0,
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p1,
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p2,
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p3,
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p4,
            (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p5
    WHERE (p0.n + p1.n*2 + p2.n * POWER(2,2) + p3.n * POWER(2,3)+ p4.n * POWER(2,4)+ p5.n * POWER(2,5)) <= 31
    ) WHERE dt NOT IN (SELECT DATE(created_at) FROM alert);
```

The following query returns all dates that are missing but I don't get the `alerts.alert_type_id` property from this.

I'm not sure how to turn this query to be able to go from alert_type to alert to basically get:
alert_type.name | date_missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the dates and alerts and then use `left join` or `not exists` to filter out the ones with no match

```
with pair as (
      SELECT 0 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1
     ),
     dates as (
      SELECT DATE(CURRENT_DATE - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()) AS dt
      FROM pair p0 CROSS JOIN 
           pair p1 CROSS JOIN 
           pair p2 CROSS JOIN 
           pair p3 CROSS JOIN 
           pair p4 CROSS JOIN 
           pair p5 
      LIMIT 31
     )
SELECT d.dt, alt.*
FROM dates d CROSS JOIN
     alert_type alt LEFT JOIN
     alerts a
     ON a.alert_type_id = alt.alert_type_id AND
        a.created_at::date = d.dt
WHERE a.alert_type_id IS NULL;
```

I simplified a bit the part about generating the dates.

Comment: I get duplicates but should be easy to fix. You are a genius. Thank you so much. This is way better and simpler than the garbage I came up with.